# Android Geofences Without Background Location Permission - Possible?

Tags: android, background, location, android-permissions, android-geofence

According to Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing), Geofences requires ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION if your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher.

I am wondering if it is possible to use Geofences without background permission?

For example starting a Foreground Service from the app while its in foreground itself, or any other way.

Comment: Use your own geofence construct. Its only calculate the distance of two locations and compare with a radius. Google does not have to know about you doing so.

Comment: But how would the app get an alert / call back when user enters or leaves the geofence area?

Comment: Well the app checks for enter and exit and such. So its the first one who can warn the user. There is nobody else involved. And it works without wifi or mobile connection.

Comment: How would that work if the app is not in foreground? Please clarify your approach.

Comment: Your foreground service will do that. Just as you did before.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused by what you're suggesting. Geofences require background location as per docs, are you saying its possible to use them w/o it? Also, could you please clarify what you mean as "your own geofence construct". Thanks!

Comment: That is googles geofence. I suggested to make your own. As it is nothing more then calculating the distance between two locations.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. But how would that remove the need for background location? You would still need monitor location in the background.

Comment: That is a quite different problem. Of course you need location updates to use geofenced.  But as soon when you get  a new location you need nothing else to use your own geofence stuff.

Comment: Heh, ok. I see where the confusion is :) I think you understanding of what geofences are is a bit different. You describe it as calculating distance between two points which has nothing to do with geofences at all - there are geographic functions to accomplish that. This post is about Android geofences that allow you to know once user has entered or left a predefined perimeter. Sorry if that was not clear from my post.

Comment: What you're suggesting has nothing to do with my question or Android geofencing. It is more than just as simple geofence logical construct or distance between 2 points, it performs background location monitoring using GPS, the fact that I mention location permissions in the question should have given that away. Docs link I included will provide more info if interested.